# setting model workspace from script (and saving the setting)

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I made a model using ModelBuilder. User must be able to specify output featureclasses by basename, I do not want to expose the workspace. The workspace therefore needs to be specified in the model environment.
The workspace can be derived from the other specifics.

A savvy user can do this in the toolbox window, however, I want to make it automatic.
So, I'm looking for a way to set toolbox environment variables by means of python script.
My ArcGIS version is 9.3.1. However, I'm interested in advice pertaining to version 10+ as well, since it just might put me on the right track.

Comment: I think this thread has some options and answeres,

try
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66578/python-setting-workspace-as-variable

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to create a static workspace name?

Why not add a workspace variable to your model and reference it with inline substitution? This is discussed in the help file.

You could expose it as a parameter if you want them to be able to change it.